# Jquery not working on notepad++ but works in rails

Tags: jquery

I have built a site using ruby on rails on my cloud 9 account. I have all my CSS and HTML located here also.

I am  not trying to copy my HTML and CSS to notepad++ and all is working fine. However my Jquery is not working. It works fine on rails however.

I have checked the errors and while Jquery is being called it does not seem to recognize the code.

Can anyone see a problem with this code and a reason why it would work on rails and not on notepad++?

JQuery

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.nafianna').hide();
            $('.castleknock').hide();
            $('.clontarf').hide();
            $('.erinsisle').hide();
            $('.setenta').hide();
            $('.skerries').hide(); 
            $('.stvincents').hide();

     $('#club').change(function () {
      if ($(this).val() == "Empty") {
            $('.nafianna').hide();
            $('.castleknock').hide();
            $('.clontarf').hide();
            $('.erinsisle').hide();
            $('.setenta').hide();
            $('.skerries').hide(); 
            $('.stvincents').hide();
      }
      else if ($(this).val() == "NaFianna") {
            $('.nafianna').show();
            $('.castleknock, .clontarf, .erinsisle, .setenta, .skerries, .stvincents').hide();
      } 
      else if ($(this).val() == "Castleknock") {
            $('.castleknock').show();
          $('.nafianna, .clontarf, .erinsisle, .setenta, .skerries, .stvincents').hide();
      }
      else if ($(this).val() == "Clontarf") {
            $('.clontarf').show();
           $('.nafianna, .castleknock, .erinsisle, .setenta, .skerries, .stvincents').hide();
      }
       else if ($(this).val() == "ErinsIsle") {
            $('.erinsisle').show();
            $('.nafianna, .castleknock, .clontarf, .setenta, .skerries, .stvincents').hide();
      }
       else if ($(this).val() == "Setenta") {
            $('.setenta').show();
            $('.nafianna, .castleknock, .clontarf, .erinsisle, .skerries, .stvincents').hide();
      }
       else if ($(this).val() == "Skerries") {
            $('.skerries').show();
            $('.nafianna, .castleknock, .clontarf, .erinsisle, .setenta, .stvincents').hide();
      }
       else if ($(this).val() == "StVincents") {
            $('.stvincents').show();
            $('.nafianna, .castleknock, .clontarf, .erinsisle, .setenta, .skerries').hide();
      }
});
});
```

The idea is that maps are displayed depending on users selection from a drop down menu.

I'm sure it is something simple as it is working in rails fine.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: path to include the appropriate jquery files?  Are they actually loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code before your head closure (**</head>**)

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#club').on('change',function(){
           var allClasses=".nafianna, .castleknock, .clontarf, .erinsisle, .setenta, .skerries, .stvincents";
           var activeClass=$(this).val().toLowerCase();
           $(allClasses).hide();
           $('.'+activeClass).show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Vixed. Its really appreciated. And your code is obviously more refined than mine (I am pretty new to this) so I will try to implement yours . When you say the problem is just the path do you mean the path I have added to the top of my HTML in order to call the function?

Comment: @NiallL can you please test my last version of the code? I would like also to see some sample of your html page.

Comment: thanks for your help. I have now been able to get it working thanks to your assistance. Thanks again, Niall

Answer (score 1):

like Vixed said, you can also add this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```